# out of memory error in android..

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

my app is using some 15 odd images all around 30-50 kb. it has a splash screen and a main activity and an inner page. splash screen and main activity page loads alrt.. but when inner page is accessed am getting the following error

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
```

am not using bitmap factory.. an image toggle is just occurring here with

```
 setBackgroundResource
```

also i have provided

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

to the manifest.. my log cat is provided below..

```
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15303)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at com.quinoid.tI.Home_Screen$1.onClick(Home_Screen.java:44)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 06-09 04:29:04.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the class file (home_screen.java)

```
 home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { <--line 44

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home1);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Home_Screen.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

so what can i do  here??

Comment: Why you do this: home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home1); when you are going to leave activity ?

Comment: am changing an image on the icon... @Ultimo_m the transition time is slow.. thus there is a button image change which the user sees

Comment: I think the best solution for you would be using drawable, here is a link that does that http://stackoverflow.com/a/15287256/2736039

Comment: Another thing, if you remove that line of code does the error happens ?

Comment: yep.. if setbackgroundresource is commented the app works @Ultimo_m

Comment: Search SO - there are _hundreds_ of questions dealing with this error.

Comment: Then try the link i gave you and see if it works for you

Comment: @Ultimo_m background drawable cant be implemented .. the image type in r.java - drawable is int

Comment: Do you have the images in drawable folder ?

Comment: yes all the images are in the drawable folder @Ultimo_m

Comment: its better if your go with selectors,you can define all the states in selected like pressed,onfocus etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity XML in your home Button you should add this :

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
```

Then you should create btn_selector.xml file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home1"  android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/(put your image when image isnt pressed)" />
 </selector>
```